# Android Set views in fragment from Parent Activity in View Pager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity which uses ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter to setup three fragments. Now when the activity loads, I issue a network request and plan to update the views in three fragments on reply from network. Now I am having difficulty to set those views from the main activity. Things I have tried (and spectacularly failed) are :

- Create a setter in Fragment Class to set the view data. In the fragment `onViewCreated` method I am saving global view references of textviews, and then try to call that setter from Activity on network load. The textviews are NULL, i.e not even instantiated when setter is called.
- Create a getter in Activity to get the data from Fragments `onViewCreated` method.But in this case, the getter wont find the values as network request is not complete!

Any tips how to proceed? I have three fragments with related data and want to control their view settings from a single point. I dont want to make separate network calls from each Fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Create a setter in Fragment Class to set the view data. In the fragment `onViewCreated` method I am saving global view references of
>     textviews, and then try to call that setter from Activity on network
>     load. The textviews are NULL, i.e not even instantiated when setter is
>     called.

You're doing it right.

Why do those textviews have NULL value is all about a fragment reference you use when you call the setter method.

In short: add this function to your FragmentPagerAdapter implementation

```
public Fragment getFragmentByPositionUsingTag(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":" + position);

    return fragment;
}
```

and try to use the reference it returns to call the method. (For more information there are many great answers on SO).

Comment: awesome. Thanks a lot! Btw is there a way to get the Fragment by title instead of position?

Comment: one problem i am facing though, as I said I have three fragments, so when I swipe to other fragments and then come back to the first the set Text is gone and findFragmentByTag returns null. is it because fragments internally gets detached?

Comment: create two arraylists to store fragments' references and titles. 1. you can connect positions to titles 2. if findFragmentByTag returns null, then try to use a reference from arraylist (but only if findFragmentByTag returns null). Experiment with it